# Why my derivatives of the equvalent trigonometric functions are different?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need to differentiate $$F=2\cos(x)-\sin(2x)$$$$ F'=−2\sin(x)−2\cos(2x)=0$$ And Extrema should be $$\sin(x)=-\frac{1}{2},\sin(x)=1$$

But when I do it like that:$$F=2\cos(x)-\sin(2x)
=2\cos(x)-2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$$$F'=-2\sin(x)-2(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))=0$$$$-2\sin(x)-2\cos^2(x)+2\sin^2(x)=0$$$$2(-\sin(x)-\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))=0$$$$2(-\sin(x)-1)=0$$$$\sin(x)=-1$$

Comment: Minor aesthetic quibble but write "\" before any trigonometric term to change $sin(x)$ to $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Right near the end, you reduced "$-\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)$" to "$-1$". (The sign on "$\sin^2(x)$" would need to be "$-$" for that.)

Comment: thesmallprint, thank you. I edited.

Comment: Blue, thank you! Now I've got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem arises from this line $$2(-\sin(x)-\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)).$$ It turns out that $-\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)\neq -1$. It's actually $-\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=-1$.

Comment: thank you again :)

Comment: No worries my friend!